# Subquery selecting over a select

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have a table `users` structured as follow:

```
userUID (int), userName (varchar), userImage (varchar)
```

And a table 'posts' structured as follow

```
postPID (int), postUID (int), postMessage (char)
```

Now, the `postUID` correspond to the author `UID`.
When i `SELECT` the posts, i'd like to also select the `userName` and `userImage` field corresponding to the `postUID`.

How could i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  p.*, u.userName, u.userImage
FROM    users u
JOIN    posts p
ON      p.postUID = u.userUID
```

Comment: Just another more question (i tried to google it but couldn't find anything): what does `ON` means? Is it something like `WHERE`?

Comment: @Charlie: google for `ANSI join syntax`. In your case, it's almost like a `WHERE` condition, but it would not be if you used `LEFT JOIN` (which is not rewritable only using `WHERE`).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
  p.postPID,
  p.postUID,
  p.postMessage,
  u.userName,
  u.userImage
From posts p
  Join users u
    On p.postUID = u.userUID
```

It's better to name your columns instead of selecting * as has been discussed on here in numerous threads.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many records are returned. If not sure it is good to have `top 10` or `top 100` so that it only returns that many rows.